# Finding eccentricity of plotted ellipse in matlab

Tags: matlab, ellipse

I am new to matlab, so this might be a trivial question. But I couldn't find any help googling, regarding this. I have a set of points, and from that I have found a minimum bounding ellipse, enclosing those points. The function returns the center of the ellipse, and a matrix A (in center form). I need to find eccentricity of the ellipse, along with properties like semi-axes lengths of the same ellipse.

And some pointers as to what exactly A contains, is also appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have a set of points, why not use regionprops() function? This function can be used to analyze eccentricity and many other properties.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the function. Actually, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you construct your ellipse you can use regionprops() function to get properties of the ellipse object.

```
s = regionprops(bw, 'Orientation', 'MajorAxisLength', ...
    'MinorAxisLength', 'Eccentricity')
```

For more on how to contruct your object read http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/07/30/visualizing-regionprops-ellipse-measurements/

Comment: Thanks but, how can I pass the ellipse here ? I mean according to the link, 'bw' should be an image. And I have an ellipse defined by just [A, c]. c = center and A is a n X n matrix. (in n-D space).